# AutoHotKey mapping

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to map the following key combinations on my keyboard using AutoHotkey -

Alt i -> Up Arrow
Alt j -> Left Arrow
Alt k -> Right Arrow
Alt m -> Down Arrow

I added the following code to my AutoHotkey.ahk file -

```
!i::Up
!j::Down
!m::Left
!k::Right
```

but it doesn't produce the desired results. Please help!!

Comment: @marc AHK scripting is bona fide programming and fits better here than on SU.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
!i::SendInput,{UP}
!j::SendInput,{LEFT}
!k::SendInput,{RIGHT}
!m::SendInput,{DOWN}
```

Comment: The above settings worked but I had another question related to this. It seems that even though pressing Alt i causes the cursor to move left, if I use Alt i while simultaneously holding down Shift, it doesn't produce the same results as holding down Shift and pressing left arrow, i.e. the text in an editor getting selected as a result of this. Is there a way for AutoHotKey to get Alt i with Shift held down to behave exactly like Shift + Left Arrow?

Comment: I *think* you need to map that explicitly: `+!i::SendInput,!{UP}`

Answer (score 1):

Jay's answer works, but

```
!i::Send {Up}
Return
!k::Send {Down}
Return
!l::Send {Right}
Return
!j::Send {Left}
Return
```

is a much faster solution.

Comment: If your command is a one-liner, you don't need to put `return` on the next line.

Comment: @Miguel Why would returns make it faster?  Unless the Send does it, in which case BGM is correct that the returns should be unnecessary...

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach is to use the freeware application TouchCursor http://touchcursor.sourceforge.net/overview.html It has training mode, is easier to configure. Also, I was surprised to learn that using 'space' rather than 'alt' works much better in practice.

Comment: This question is tagged autohotkey - the fellow wants help with autohotkey, not some other application.